# Display a different side-nav on a different page using materialize css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

I am making a simple page where I wanted to display different side-nav class when going to another page. I am using materialize css and I made a custom css to override the side-nav class now I wanted to display the normal side-nav when going to another page. Is there a better way to do it? I need some advice from you guys and that would be a big help.

Example HTML:

```
<nav class="white lighten-1" role="navigation">
  <div class="nav-wrapper container"><a id="logo-container" href="#" class="brand-logo center"></a>
    <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
     <div class="right">
       <li><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn grey lighten-1">Login</a></li>
       <li><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn red lighten-1">Register</a></li>
     </div>
    </ul>

    <ul id="nav-mobile" class="side-nav fixed">
     <div class="list-group">
      <a class="list-group-item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; User
      </a>
      <a class="list-group-item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-search fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; Search
      </a>
    </div>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" data-activates="nav-mobile" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
  </div>
</nav><!-- nav ending -->
```

CSS:

```
.side-nav {
 background-color: #27AEEB;
 color: #ffffff;
 margin-top: 75px;
 margin-left: 8px;
 height: 47%;
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by normal side-nav you mean to load the default side-nav, then you may have all your side-nav specific CSS in an altogether different class, rather than the `.side-nav` class which you are currently using. You can have a, let's say a `.custom-side-nav` class, meaning your `ul` tag having `.side-nav` class should look like `<ul id="nav-mobile" class="side-nav custom-side-nav fixed">`. And your CSS should look like:

```
.custom-side-nav {
    background-color: #27AEEB;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin-top: 75px;
    margin-left: 8px;
    height: 47%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Then, whenever you navigate to another page you can get back your so-called 'normal' side-nav using jQuery by removing the `.custom-side-nav` class from your side-nav. You can do it using [`.removeClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) method, like `$("#nav-mobile").removeClass("custom-side-nav")`. This way, you can later have your custom CSS applied again on your side-nav if you visit this page again simply by having a `$("#nav-mobile").addClass("custom-side-nav")`.

Let me know if I misinterpreted your question, in which case you may have to put some more light on what you exactly desire to achieve so that we can all work on a concrete solution.

Comment: This post is useful. Thanks

Comment: Glad to help! :) Don't forget to mark it as a solution if it solved your problem for our other fellow-developers to follow suit who may encounter something similar in future.

Comment: Actually I haven't tried this one. Instead I use the original side-nav on my project. I try this one if I have a free time. I'll get back later and accept this if it works.